# Force clear EJB3 cache in Glassfish

Tags: java, caching, glassfish, ejb-3.0, toplink-essentials

I have application written in Java that is using EJB3 + Toplink. I'm using Glassfish as my app. server.

Sometimes the data that has been cached is old and I need to clear my cache manually. I [know](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4343/6nfqjnv32?a=view) that we can set time to clear it, but I would like to make a button that will manually clear it for me. Is is possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can refresh cache with you query your database using this code:

```
Query query = em.createQuery(sql.toString()).setHint("toplink.refresh", "true");
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use:

```
em.createNamedQuery("findAll").setHint(QueryHints.CACHE_RETRIEVE_MODE, CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS).getResultList();
```

it works for me and I think it is more standard way.